# How to create a Canvas object inside a Paintbox on Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

On a **Form** I've put a **Paintbox** with the property *Align = alClient* and a **Button**.
I need to draw a object of **Canvas** type inside the **PaintBox** in the *OnClick* event of the **Button**.

This is the **Canvas** object that will be created:

```
const IconSize:Integer = 10
type
  Icon = Class   
  public
    posX, posY:Integer;
    constructor Create(X,Y:Integer);
    destructor Destroy;
    procedure SetX(AValue: Integer);
    procedure SetY(AValue: Integer);
  published
    property LocationX : Integer read posX write SetX;
    property LocationY : Integer read posY write SetY;
end;     
var CanvasIcon: Icon;
```

This is *constructor* method of the object:

```
constructor Icon.Create(X, Y: Integer);
var Bitmap:TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Height := IconSize;
    Bitmap.Width := IconSize;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(Round(X-(IconSize/2)), Round(Y-(IconSize/2)),
      Round(X+(IconSize/2)), Round(Y+(IconSize/2)));
    PaintBox.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is the *OnClick* event of the **Button**:

```
procedure TFormPaintBox.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CanvasIcon:=Icon.Create(10,10);
end;
```

However, the Lazarus show the follow message:

> src/unitpaintbox.pas(121,33) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "Create"

But the *constructor* receive two parameters, exactly like was specified on  *onClick* event of the **Button**. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't *draw a Canvas*, you draw **on** a Canvas. The TPaintBox already has a canvas; you simply draw your graphics on that canvas. It's also convention that classes and other types begin with `T`, which is why it's called `TPaintBox`, `TBitmap`, and `TCanvas`. It makes it clear, so that when you see `Icon` in the code you don't have to wonder if it's a type `Icon = class()` or a variable `var Icon: TIcon;`. `TCanvas` has a constructor already which accepts no parameters (`Canvas := TCanvas.Create;`).

Comment: _"TCanvas is a class capable of executing drawings. It cannot exist alone and must either be attached to something visible (or at least which may possibly be visible), such as a visual control descending from TControl, or be attached to an off-screen buffer from a TRasterImage descendent (TBitmap is the most commonly used). "_ from [Developing with Graphics](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Developing_with_Graphics)

Comment: Because you don't follow general conventions (as Ken already said), it is hard to see what is wrong. Most likely is having some other "icon" in the scope, as a property or field of the form or so.

Comment: It was solved when I did the changes Ken White said and changed the name `Icon` for `CustomIcon`. It looks was a conflict issue, `Icon` already exists.